# tab bar with navigation controller on each tab item - orientation problems

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

i have one tab bar controller with 4 navigation controller connection 4 tab bar items.

I made the following changes in the following controllers

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

1. All view controllers.
2. All navigation controllers.
3. 1 tabbar controller.

What else should be done to fix this ?

[reposting again !]

Comment: what's the problem you're seeing? and you don't need to override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in UINavigationController.

Comment: I tried that as well. But no effect !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, seeing your question remains unanswered after a day, I'll try to answer it even though you haven't really explained what the problem is.

To provide auto-rotation in a tab bar application, you need to implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in:

1. All your view controllers
2. Your tab bar controller

You **don't** need to subclass `UINavigationController`, just `UITabBarController`.

After you've subclassed `UITabBarController`, make sure you set the class of your tab bar controller instance to your subclass in Interface Builder.

Also, the proper implementation of `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` for an iPhone application is:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

so that the user can "lock" the orientation to landscape by turning the phone upside down.